# Wireless display plus touch input

Tags: android, windows, chromecast, miracast

Through the use of Miracast or Chromecast we can display our smartphone/windows content onto a display wirelessly. Is there a way to enable touch on the display that is being projected to wirelessly instead of using a usb cable(for windows)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, neither Miracast nor Chromecast mirroring provides that.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the UIBC function of Miracast